# Power automate flow - Create folder save email attachment to folder weekly. ** Folder name changes weekly

Tags: power-automate

To clarify

I am looking for information on creating a flow that sends and emailed attachment to a folder. However the folder name changes every week. Ex. 1-19-24. How do I send the emailed attachment to the latest folder every week.

Answer (score 0):

The `Folder Path` field in the `Create file` action is a string, so select the parent folder from the list, then append the folder name to end.

[image]

For your Folder Week Name, you can use this expression to get Friday's date:

```
addDays(utcNow(), sub(-2,dayOfWeek(utcNow())), 'dd-MMM-yyyy')
```

You will need to decide what happens on Friday, should it use this Friday's folder (if it has been created) or last Friday's folder.

This is what I have:

[image]

Comment: So use the above in the answer. Do the same thing but use the expression in the answer to get last Friday's date. DO ensure the date format matches what you have used. Change `'dd-MMM-yyyy'` to match.